# Introductory example of $\phi$ with infinitely many eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am looking for an example of a linear space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ and an endomorphism $\phi : V \to V$ such that each $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is an eigenvalue of $\phi$. One relatively simple example would be an endomorphism given by the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0   &a_2& 0 & \cdots \\
0   & 0 & a_3&\cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $a_1, a_2, \dots$ are all eigenvalues associated with unit vectors $e_1, e_2, \dots$. We could possibly have infinitely many such eigenvalues. My problem here is that this still seems to be slightly complicated as the material I am going over has not introduced infinite dimensional vector spaces. Is there a more straightforward finite dimension example I am somehow missing?

Comment: In the finite dimensional case, you will have only finitely many eigenvalues

Comment: Eigenvectors associated to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent, so this sort of construction is the best you can do; the dimension of the underlying vector space is an upper bound on the number of distinct eigenvalues, even in the infinite-dimensional case.

Comment: @D_S One question. It bothers me that in my example, the set of eigenvectors $E$ (and the corresponding set of eigenvalues) satisfies $\lvert E \rvert = \lvert \mathbb{N} \rvert < \lvert \mathbb{R} \rvert$. Doesn't this mean that we can't claim that every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: Right, you only have countably many eigenvalues.  In general, the cardinality of eigenvalues cannot exceed the dimension of your vector space.

Comment: Your example can be modified.  Let $$V = \bigoplus\limits_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \mathbb{R}$$ and for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, let $e_x$ be the element with $1$ in the $x$ place, $0$ elsewhere.  This is a basis for $V$.   You can define a linear operator $T$ on $V$ by sending $e_x$ to $xe_x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, we need to consider something over an infinite dimensional space, however you slice it.  As you've said, however, infinite matrices are a bit bizarre.

Here's a more "familiar" example: let $V$ denote the vector space of all smooth (infinitely differentiable) functions.  Consider $\phi:V \to V$ to be the "derivative map", defined by $\phi(f) = f'$.  We note that for any $\lambda \in \Bbb R$, the equation
$$
\phi(f) = \lambda f
$$
has the solution $f(x) = e^{\lambda x}$.  So, **every** real number is an eigenvalue of $\phi$.

Comment: There are a lot of very strange things about my choice of vector space and linear map from a functional analysis perspective.  However, it certainly does the job.

Comment: This is a great example and it doesn't seem to suffer from the problem I mentioned above. Thanks!